# Is this WSAPoll bug for non-blocking sockets fixed?

Tags: windows, delphi, sockets

I was looking at converting from select() to WSAPoll()/poll() for my non-blocking socket server in Delphi, and I came across [this conversation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/18769abd-fca0-4d3c-9884-1a38ce27ae90/wsapoll-and-nonblocking-connects-to-nonexistent-ports?forum=wsk) that describes a serious flaw in WSAPoll. Does anyone know if there's a fix or work-around for WSAPoll? Or is my only option  the additional work of I/O completion ports?

Comment: I read the link you posted and it seems the answer is no it's not fixed and yes there is a workaround.

Comment: Thanks. I've already read the information on that link. I was asking about a workaround specifically to fix the bug in WSAPoll, not a workaround that involved using either I/O completion ports or select().

Comment: @John Why are you still using async sockets? Still using Windows 3.11?

Comment: I think you can still use WSAPoll when you implement the timeout yourself. Any serious network application needs to implement an i/o timeout mechanism anyway.

Comment: Wow. Voting me down for asking if there's a reasonable work-around for a serious flaw in a Windows socket method is seriously not cool.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am trying to create a very simple cross-platform async socket component for IPC among platforms. Eventually I'll probably implement platform-specific higher performance methods, but right now I'm trying to get the basics working with similar code. What do you suggest I use instead? IIUC iocp is unique to Windows, and poll() has greatest xplat compatibility.

Comment: I would avoid async like the plague. If you want xplat then surely blocking io is what you need. And as for the down votes, I'd judge they are a reaction to your responses. You ask if there is a fix, then when you are told that there is no fix you somewhat demeamingly say that you already knew that there was no fix. In which case why did you ask that. If you want a workaround, ask for that, and give more detail.

Comment: I did ask if there was a workaround. I also asked if iocp was the best option to use if WSAPoll was not an option. I need to support streaming on multiple sockets at the same time, so I am working with non-blocking sockets. I provided the link I found about the bug as a context for the questions I was asking. I didn't think having the information in the link tossed back at me as the answer was helpful. I was trying to keep the question very short and to the point. "I don't know of any direct fix, so I suggest you use <x> instead" would have been helpful.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for your responses. I'm curious why you think non-blocking sockets are only useful for Windows 3.11.

Comment: Well, they were invented because Win16 had no threads and could not fork. But io is much simpler in blocking form. I'm not even sure that all platforms support async io. Why do you choose to use async?

Comment: These sockets are primarily going to be for streaming applications with multiple connections.

Comment: Blocking sockets are just fine. Async sockets are a pain in the backside. Blocking sockets are simple.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Non-blocking I/O was invented decades before Windows, and was present in Unix when Windows were just a gleam in the eye.

Comment: @EJP OK, but blocking I/O was a non-starter in Win16 because it lacked threads and fork. So that was all there was, and Windows programmers learnt that I/O is async. But if you need to service a lot of connections then async may be necessary.

Comment: @EJP and David thanks for continuing the conversation after the misunderstanding. Sounds like I'm correct in pursuing async sockets for my implementation, and that I'll have to implement platform-specific code for the best solution for non-blocking sockets, and use something other than WSAPoll.

Answer (score 4):

Your own link says it was classified as "won't fix" by Microsoft. That means they decided not to fix it. So you can assume it isn't fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I've already read the information on that link. Clearly I am asking for information for anyone who might know anything that is more current or helpful than that link.

Comment: Well that's still the answer. When a bug is marked "won't be fixed", it won't be fixed. You seem to be blaming me for the non-helpfulness of the link.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Thank you. Some answers just aren't what people want to hear.

Comment: +1 Won't fix might be unwelcome news, but let's not shoot the messenger

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. Answering my actual questions would have been more helpful, rather than telling me what I'd already read. Looks like I'll need to phrase my questions more explicitly in the future. I'm not blaming you for the "won't fix" but simply repeating what the link said can't be construed as a constructive response.

Comment: @JohnKaster It seems to me that the issue here is that you didn't understand what you had read, or at least underestimated the strength of 'will not fix'. It's a permanent decision of a policy nature, not just some evaluator's too-hard basket comment. So I tired to explain it to you. Still not convinced that you get it.

Comment: oh, I get it. Sorry you think I don't. Thanks for your efforts and sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: In the long run, it's nice to be proven right.

Comment: @JohnKaster Proven right about what? All I did here was quote your own link at you, which already answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

This was fixed in Windows 10 version 2004, documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsapoll

> Note  As of Windows 10 version 2004, when a TCP socket fails to connect, (POLLHUP | POLLERR | POLLWRNORM) is indicated.

Comment: "*documentation is pending*" - the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsapoll) was updated a few days after this answer was posted. It now states: "*Note: As of Windows 10 version 2004, when a TCP socket fails to connect, (POLLHUP | POLLERR | POLLWRNORM) is indicated.*"

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau! Updated the answer accordingly.